# tcpdump, determine transport protocol

Tags: tcp, tcpdump, udp

Is there a easy way to determine the transport protocol of a packet by looking at the output of a TCP dump trace?

I'd just like to be able to tell if a packet is UDP or TCP.  I've tried using the ***-x*** switch to look at the protocol field in the header and looking for a 6 or 17, but the hex output is pretty cumbersome to decode visually, especially for long traces.

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: With the `-v` flag?

Comment: *"Is there a easy way to determine the transport protocol of a packet by looking at the output of a TCP dump trace?"* - this solely depends on the kind of protocol and on your experience. tcpdump itself does not offer some application layer protocol detection.